# Explanation on lint warnings for some of my properties

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-lint

Analyzing code I found these warnings.
Could someone explain me some details about them please.
Any alternatives will be welcome

```
interface A {
   var someBoolean: Boolean // Boolean method 'someBoolean' is always inverted
}

class B {
   var visible: Boolean by mutableStateOf(false) // Method 'visible' is always inverted + The method is empty
       private set // The method is empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" is not usually there. You have to check *how* you use these methods.

Do you always use these methods in a "not" expression (ie. !someBoolean, !visible, ...)? If so, linter thinks it would be a better idea to reverse the logic of the method so you dont't always have to use the NOT operator.

*“Negatives are just a bit harder to understand than positives. So, when possible, conditionals should be expressed as positives.”* ([4. Avoiding negative conditionals](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/09/the-inspection-connection-issue-2/))